# Dividir un data frame utilizando una palabra clave

Tags: r, bucle-for, dataframe, grep

Holi, estoy intentando obtener multiples dataframes de un dataframe gigante. La palabra "moneda" marca el corte entre cada sección ("moneda: pesos, moneda: dolares, etc.), por lo que pensé en buscar la palabra, obtener el numero de índice donde aparece y armar un bucle for que me devuelva los distintos sets, delimitando las filas entre la primera aparicion y la siguiente. El código que armé es:

```
a = grep("Moneda", datos$FCI, ignore.case= TRUE)
datos1 = for (i in a) { datos = datos[i:i+1,]}
```

Y esto me devuelve datos1 = NULL

Entiendo que ahi no estoy generando un nuevo nombre para cada mini dataframe, pero cuando probé:

```
a = grep("Moneda", datos$FCI, ignore.case= TRUE)
x = 1:100
datos1 = for (i in a) { for (m in x){m}  = datos[i:i+1,]}
```

Ni siquiera me deja ejecutarlo.

Alguna idea de como resolverlo o alguna función diferente que pueda simplificar el proceso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `for` en R es una función que retorna siempre `NULL`, básicamente por que se trata de una estructura de control no pensada para retornar un dato, por lo que esto `datos1 = for (i in a) { datos = datos[i:i+1,]}` no tiene sentido. Si lo quisieras resolver con un `for` puedes trabajar con una lista que declararías antes y le asignarías una porción del `data.frame` a cada elemento.

```
a = grep("Moneda", datos$FCI, ignore.case= TRUE)
# agregamos a la lista el primer índice y el último
a <- unique(c(1, a, nrow(datos) + 1))
datos1 <- list(0)
for (i in 1:(length(a)-1)) {
  datos1[[i]] = datos[a[i]:(a[i+1]-1),]
}
```

Lo que se hace es ir "recortando" desde la primer fila y hasta la última,  asignado  cada parte a un nuevo elemento del `data.frame`

Por otro lado, una forma más compacta de resolverlo podría ser la siguiente:

```
datos1 = split(datos, cumsum(grepl("Moneda", datos$FCI, ignore.case= TRUE)))
```

`split()` es una función que "divide" el `data.frame` por partes, a partir de la repetición de ciertas valores, en este caso, `cumsum(grepl("Moneda", datos$FCI, ignore.case= TRUE))` que repite cierto valor hasta la aparición de un coincidencia.